# Rownum for a column with lag

Tags: oracle, lag, rownum

I have this query

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LAG(emp_id) OVER( ORDER BY NULL ) = emp_id THEN '-'
            ELSE  emp_id END "Employee ID",
       row_number() over (partition by emp_id order by emp_id) as "S/N",  
       family_mem_id   "MemID",
       CASE WHEN LAG(emp_id) OVER(ORDER BY NULL ) = emp_id THEN 0 
            ELSE (SUM(amount_paid) OVER(PARTITION BY emp_id)) END "Total amount"
FROM    Employee 
ORDER   BY emp_id;
```

And it shows me result like this: [Resultset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0MzY.jpg)

I want to add row number (first column SN) for Employee ID for in between rows I want to set it as null, for e.g. For Employee ID -> S/N 2-> F904 (SN should be null). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the outer query to create the `SN` column as follows:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN "S/N" = 1 THEN '<1>' END AS SN, T.* FROM -- added this
(SELECT 
       CASE WHEN LAG(emp_id) OVER( ORDER BY NULL ) = emp_id THEN '-'
            ELSE  emp_id END "Employee ID",
       row_number() over (partition by emp_id order by emp_id) as "S/N",  
       family_mem_id   "MemID",
       CASE WHEN LAG(emp_id) OVER(ORDER BY NULL ) = emp_id THEN 0 
            ELSE (SUM(amount_paid) OVER(PARTITION BY emp_id)) END "Total amount"
FROM    Employee ) T
ORDER BY "Employee ID", "S/N"; -- Added this
```

Note that I have also changed the `ORDER BY` clause (which is moved to the outer query).

Cheers!!

Comment: Actually I want to add serial number to "Employee id " field which increment for new employee id and display it in "SN" column(first col), please suggest how can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dense_rank()` to enumerate rows:

```
select case lag(emp_id) over( order by emp_id ) when emp_id then null 
            else '<'||dense_rank() over (order by emp_id)||'>'
       end sn,
       nullif(emp_id, lag(emp_id) over( order by emp_id )) empid,
       row_number() over (partition by emp_id order by emp_id) rn,  
       family_mem_id memid,
       case lag(emp_id) over(order by emp_id) when emp_id then null 
            else (sum(amount_paid) over(partition by emp_id)) 
       end total
  FROM  Employee order by emp_id;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cdd0d5a123972ca973b96293343b0f2b) and sample output:

```
SN   EMPID     RN MEMID      TOTAL
---- ----- ------ ----- ----------
<1>  101        1 F901         200
                2 F904  
<2>  102        1 F901         135
                2 F901  
<3>  103        1 F901         185
                2 F901  
                3 F901
```

Comment: Great, its perfect

Comment: I want to replace all nulls with spaces any suggestions for that.

Comment: Use space instead of null in `case when`. For non varchar columns you have to convert values, use `to_char()`. You may also put `0` in sum column as you did in your question. [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=df1ff2eab198db2b0d037b5ebb5ac102).